# Why doesn't the margin work for elements inside the recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Why doesn't the margin work for elements inside the recyclerview? I searched for a solution to the problem, nothing worked in my case. The changes are displayed in android studio, but not on the emulator.

But when I add margin for recyclerview, the elements move left/up/right. But I can't make the distance between the elements.

This is what it looks like now:

[image: Current appearance]

**layout_file.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/radius"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-80dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/items"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="166dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="166dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/items"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="251dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="251dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/qr"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.148"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/items"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/qr_code"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <include layout="@layout/main_nav_drawer" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: try to use padding in parent

Comment: It depends which of the several margins you want to change.  A few possibilities include spacing around the RecyclerView, spacing within the list item or spacing between list items.   Also, consider embedding the image.  Maybe annotations on the image would make what want to achieve clearer.

Comment: @user650881 Yes, I want to indent between list items.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the usually recommended approach to add spacing between recycler list items is to use a [`DividerItemDecoration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html).

```java
mDividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
    mLayoutManager.getOrientation());
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(mDividerItemDecoration);
```

You can then add a drawable, possibly transparent, with the desired spacing.

```java
Drawable mySpacer = ....;
mDividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(mySpacer);
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me why I can't achieve the same thing with margin/padding?

Comment: You can give spcace between items by just add android:layout_marginBottom="" in parent of item layout . and your links is also not working.

Comment: Here is an article arguing the advantages of a decorator over margins. https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/right-way-of-setting-margin-on-recycler-views-cell-319da259b641.  The topic is also addressed in a number of other places.

Comment: But it is wrong way to do. and you have add just one line in layout it will get work without hack

Comment: It is not working. and you can add space by one line then why to go for this?